# what's the differences of url-loader , file-loader , and image-loader

Tags: webpack

I'm so confused about url-loader , file-loader  and image-loader .  Can anybody explain me what's the differences of url-loader , file-loader , and image-loader and why we need all of them . thanks !

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

The `url-loader` works like the `file-loader`, but can return a Data Url if the file is smaller than a limit.

The limit can be specified with a query parameter.

Comment: Well url-loader and image-loader can both do the same things afaik... does anyone know which one is best for inlining images?? (svg , png)

Comment: @Spock use `url-loader`